# There is no argument that corresponds to the required formal parameter constructor help needed

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, constructor

Having trouble using a constructor in a class that inherits from a base class

```
    public class PlayerSpell : ScriptableObject
{
    protected P_Base player;

    public string spellName = "base";
    public int cost = 0;
    public string category = "utility";
    public ScriptableObject spellData;
    public PlayerState spellState;

    [Header("Allowed Classes")]
    public int[] classes;

    public PlayerSpell(PlayerState spellState, string spellName, int cost, string category, PlayerSpell spellData, int[] classes)
    {

    }
}
```

Simple constructor in the base class above.

```
public class DashSpell : PlayerSpell
{

    public DashSpell(PlayerState spellState, string spellName, int cost, string category, PlayerSpell spellData, int[] classes)
    {
        this.spellState = spellState;
        this.spellName = spellName;
        this.cost = cost;
        this.category = category;
        this.spellData = spellData;
        this.classes = classes;
    }

}
```

Trying to store the values of the scriptable object in said constructor
Getting the error "There is no argument that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'spellState' of PlayerSpell.PlayerSpell(...)

Comment: add ```: base(spellState, spellName ...)``` to DashSpell constructor

Comment: Your object is a `ScriptableObject` => **It may not have a constructor!** it is also not allowed to use `new` in order to create an instance. Rather use either `ScriptableObject.CreateInstance<Type>` or `Instantiate` ... then rather make you stuff in e.g. a `public void Initialize(PlayerState ....)`

Comment: @AdamStawarek no this is not allowed in Unity ... no class inheriting from `UnityEngine.Object` (including e.g. `GameObject`, `MonoBehaviour`, `ScriptableObject`) may have a constructor nor be created using `new`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your object is a [`ScriptableObject`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ScriptableObject.html) which inherits from [`UnityEngine.Object`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.html)

=> **It may not implement a constructor!**

It is also **not allowed** to use `new` in order to create an instance.

Unity constructs and handles instantiation internally.

---

Rather use either [`ScriptableObject.CreateInstance<Type>`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ScriptableObject.CreateInstance.html) or `Instantiate` (for copy an existing one) ... then rather make you stuff in e.g. a

```
public void Initialize(PlayerState spellState, string spellName, int cost, string category, PlayerSpell spellData, int[] classes)
{
    this.spellState = spellState;
    this.spellName = spellName;
    this.cost = cost;
    this.category = category;
    this.spellData = spellData;
    this.classes = classes;
}
```

then you could do

```
var dashSpell = ScriptableObject.CreateInstance<DashSpell>();
dashSpell.Initialize(........);
```

---

Alternatively you could also have a factory method like

```
public static DashSpell Create(PlayerState spellState, string spellName, int cost, string category, PlayerSpell spellData, int[] classes)
{
    var dashSpell = ScriptableObject.CreateInstance<DashSpell>();

    dashSpell.spellState = spellState;
    dashSpell.spellName = spellName;
    dashSpell.cost = cost;
    dashSpell.category = category;
    dashSpell.spellData = spellData;
    dashSpell.classes = classes;
}
```

and use it like

```
var dashSpell = DashSpell.Create(..............);
```

---

**General note**

Usually you use `ScriptableObject` for creating them in the editor and define different settings. You usually would not create them on runtime.

It is therefore a bit questionable if you need your class to inherit from `ScriptableObject` **at all**.

Comment: I appreciate the extensive answer, just trying to find my bearings when it comes to making up this system so thank you a lot